# rename() not working in cron job

Tags: php, rename, cron

rename() runs fine from the command line, but when run from cron job, the rename() does not. Since the connect.php file works I assume the cron job is in the right directory, but can't figure out why rename() doesn't work. I tried absolute paths and they didn't work:

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';

$oldlocation='xxx/xxx/'.$oldfilename;
$newlocation='yyyy/xxx/'.$newfilename;
$move=rename("$oldlocation","$newlocation");
```

The cron job: * * * * * /usr/bin/php /usr/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.php -q -f

I have no root access to the server. Should this be run through a SHELL script?

Comment: It seems like your `$oldlocation` and `$newlocation` are given as relative paths. Cron probably executes your script from a different location, try making them absolute.

Comment: Are you sure you setup your absolute paths correctly?  Cron definitely won't work with relative paths, but you have to make sure your absolute path is defined from root - something like `include '/home/youraccount/public_html/includes/connect.php';`

Comment: the connect.php file works exactly as shown and I'm not sure why, but the rename() needs absolute paths, I was missing the / at the beginning of the path, not needed for php in a browser or command line I guess but is needed for absolute paths, I'm guessing again but will research. Thank you for the responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current path while a `cron` execution is the `home` directory of the user which is running the `cron` process. See also this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job).

Just change the relative path to an absolute and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, not directly a directory issue (well sort of):
    $oldlocation='xxx/xxx/'.$oldfilename;
has to be changed to: 
    $oldlocation='/xxx/xxx/'.$oldfilename;
I guess I was missing the first /

Comment: This is the absolute path as `jojonas`, `Sean Cunningham` and `I` mentioned. The first `/` is the character which tells the system to use an absolute path.

Comment: Yes and thank you. For some reason I was unable to find elsewhere that an absolute path must start with a / which I spent many hours trying to figure out. In the original question I mentioned that I had tried absolute paths so I knew I needed them but then in the code I showed incorrect path formatting which I couldn't, for the life of me figure out. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: Would be nice when you accept my answer as it solved your problem. Thx